# how to convert AM/PM to XX/YY in date()

Tags: php, string, datetime

I want to convert `AM` and `PM` to `XX` and `YY` in `date();` function.

here is my code:

```
echo $year = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A",time());
// output: 2015-08-08 09:21:26 PM
```

I want this: `2015-08-08 09:21:26 YY`
. Is it possible ?

Comment: `date("Y-m-d h:i:s \Y\Y",time());`?

Comment: @u_mulder your solution is fine, but what about *AM* ? I need to put `XX` instead of it.

Comment: @Sajad there's already an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a way to do.

```
 $array_from_to = array (
      'AM' => 'XX',
      'PM' => 'YY'
  );
 $year = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A",time());
 $year= strtr($year, $array_from_to);
 echo $year;
```

Demo:  http://codepad.viper-7.com/zMIpNC

Answer (score 2):

You can make this only with IF

```
$year = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",time());
if(date("A",time())=="PM"){ 
      $year.="YY"; 
}else{ 
     $year.="XX";
}
```